# Do not reset variables in beginning of function

Tags: python, variables, scope, reset

I was doing a technical interview and i got a coding task very similar to this one. Basically the same, but not with batman and a building but something else. (the test was in the same website):
https://www.codingame.com/training/medium/shadows-of-the-knight-episode-1

I have solved this before and i know the logic i should use. So when I was taking the test i wrote down my code but in the end i realized the code in the actual test is structured in a different way than in the practice section in the website. I panicked cause i was doing it for time and i could not come up with how to change the code. Here it is:

```
import sys
import math
from contextlib import redirect_stderr, redirect_stdout

def solve(direction, x,y ,width, height):
    max_x = width - 1
    max_y = height - 1
    min_x = 0
    min_y = 0
    if direction.find('U') > -1:
        max_y = y - 1
    elif direction.find('D') > -1:
        min_y = y + 1
    if direction.find('R') > -1:
        min_x = x + 1
    elif direction.find('L') > -1:
        max_x = x - 1
    curr_x = math.ceil((min_x+max_x)/2)
    curr_y = math.ceil((min_y+max_y)/2)

    return [curr_x, curr_y]

def main():
    width, height=[int(i for i in input().split())]
    #game loop

    while True:
        inputs = input().split()
        x = int(inputs[0])
        y = int(inputs[1])
        direction = inputs[2]
        with redirect_stdout(sys.stderr):
            coordinates=solve(direction, x, y, width, height)
        for i in range(2):
            print(coordinates[i])

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

So obviously this code will not work cause every time we get a new position for the "batman" we call the solve function and the variables are reset.
So i do not know how to structure the code so the four variables at the beginning of the function are set only the first time the function is called. (i cannot change the main method). I know that min_x and min_y i can declare before the function but what about max_x and max_y, since i am using parameters passed to the function.

Hopefully, you understood my question! Thanks for the help!

EDIT: So what the code should do - we have a grid, which represents a data center. From the input we get the width and the height of the grid. We have to find a faulty server, which is a point somewhere in the grid. We have maximum jumps constraint. We also get a direction, which leads us in which part of the grid the faulty server is. The game is an infinite loop, where we get info from the standard input and we should provide to the standard output the next movement we want to do. The goal is to get to the faulty server as soon as possible in less than the maximum jumps. I do this by checking the direction i am given and limiting the grid i have to explore. The problem is i should have max_x, max_y, min_x and min_y outside of the function. On the first call to solve they should be initialised as written, but after that i assign other values to those variables and i need them to be the same on the next call.

Comment: Please explain what it's supposed to do here, not in an external link.

Comment: Please don't point to a website, explain the problem within the context of your question.  Also, "So obviously this code will not work cause every time we get a new position for the "batman" we call the solve function and the variables are reset." is not a question.  Please ask a question for which it is possible to provide an answer.

Comment: The example produces a TypeError. Please fix.

Comment: Does this ever exit? You also need the input (as well as expected output and actual output). You could skip the stdin stuff entirely and just put the test case in the python code.

Comment: @KennyOstrom They say the `main()` function is a given.

Comment: If you need variable to persist between calls, use global variables.

Comment: @Barmar i added additional info with a question :)

Comment: @itprorh66 i added additional info and a question. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variables outside the function. Since the initial value of the max variables depends on function parameters, initialize them with an invalid value and update them on the first call.

```
max_x = max_y = None
min_x = min_y = 0

def solve(direction, x,y ,width, height):
    global max_x, max_y, min_x, min_y
    if max_x is None:
        max_x = width - 1
    if max_y is None:
        max_y = height - 1

    if 'U' in direction:
        max_y = y - 1
    elif 'D' in direction:
        min_y = y + 1
    if 'R' in direction:
        min_x = x + 1
    elif 'L' in direction:
        max_x = x - 1
    curr_x = math.ceil((min_x+max_x)/2)
    curr_y = math.ceil((min_y+max_y)/2)

    return [curr_x, curr_y]
```

The `in` operator is the more pythonic way to test if a string contains a character (or substring).

Comment: thank you so much! now that i see it it looks so easy ;x and thanks for the additional advice for the in operator